# Lat/long indexing in 2d array

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a `.nc` file where latitude and longitude are in 2d array. I want to extract the values for certain known points. I did not find the way to find the index for that known points.

data structure looks like:

```
OrderedDict([(u'lon', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
              float32 lon(y, x)
                  standard_name: longitude
                  long_name: longitude
                  units: degrees_east
                  _CoordinateAxisType: Lon
              unlimited dimensions: 
              current shape = (146, 209)
              filling off), (u'lat', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
              float32 lat(y, x)
                  standard_name: latitude
                  long_name: latitude
                  units: degrees_north
                  _CoordinateAxisType: Lat
              unlimited dimensions: 
              current shape = (146, 209)
              filling off), (u'time', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
              float64 time(time)
                  standard_name: time
                  units: seconds since 1949-12-1 00:00:00
                  calendar: proleptic_gregorian
                  axis: T
              unlimited dimensions: time
              current shape = (55152,)
              filling off), (u'TOT_PREC', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
              float32 TOT_PREC(time, y, x)
                  standard_name: precipitation_amount
                  long_name: total precipitation amount
                  units: kg m-2
                  coordinates: lat lon
                  cell_methods: time: sum
              unlimited dimensions: time
              current shape = (55152, 146, 209)
              filling off)])
```

Suppose I want to extract the values to the points whose coordinates are: `lat=27.25`, `lon=85.75` then how to get the lat and long index for those coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

First, you read the .nc file and variables inside

```
ds1 = NetCDFFile('file.nc')
ds2 = ...

lon = ds.variables['lon'][:]
lat = ds.variables['lat'][:]
```

Then write the file using 'for' loop {}{}{} lat,lon,data
then u easily read the data.
hopefully, it makes some sense.